# Circumventing sql injection by using method insert

Tags: c#, mysql

I made up a method to insert records with parameters, however I am not 100% sure if I am circumventing security from SQL injection in doing so?

Is it possible for the sql injected if I take apart the query and reassemble it in this manner?

```
string tbl = "tbl_jobLogs";
string col = "job,user,logDate,log,logType" ; //,logType";
string val = jobID.ToString() + "," + user.ToString() + "," + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss") + "," + log + "," + logType.ToString() ;

MessageBox.Show(InsertWithParameters(tbl,col,val));
```

using this method

```
string InsertWithParameters(string tbl, string col, string val)
    {
        string cnString = "connectionstring";
        string sqlParameters = col.Replace(",", ",@");
        sqlParameters = "@" + sqlParameters; //add the first @

        List<string> columns = col.Split(',').ToList<string>();
        List<string> values = val.Split(',').ToList<string>();
        List<string> paramenters = sqlParameters.Split(',').ToList<string>();


        string sql = "insert into " + tbl + " (" + col + ") values (" + sqlParameters + ")";

        try
        {
            MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(cnString);
            cnn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            for (int i = 0; i <= columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramenters[i], values[i]);
            } 

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
           // TODO: Error Log
        }

        return ("Record Inserted");
    }
```

Comment: If you're concatenating SQL strings, just assume that you've hopelessly broken security. Never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never, never do that. Not on a house, not in a mouse, not with a souse. Just don't go there.

Comment: Why would you pass in your columns and parameters as a comma-separated list, complete with conversion issues etc? Just pass in an array of strings for the column names and an array of objects for the values. No splitting etc required...

Comment: @Ed, while it might not be advisable to concatenate SQL strings, in this specific case from what I can tell so far, the SQL string is only assembled from hardcoded values (note that the values clause of SQL is filled with strings originating from the col parameter, which originates from a hardcoded string before the call). I can't see any way of a SQL injection... yet ;-)

Comment: I figured using the hardcoded column values as parameter naming would protect it as I can't see where I will be using any dynamic column names.  I will rework putting it in arrays as suggested.

Comment: The AddWithValue call is the killjoy here. All strings? [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Steve yes all string values.  Well really a couple ints and a datetime converted tostring

Comment: Strings that MySql needs to convert back to the correct datatype of the underlying column using its own rules for localization, character sets and so on. Sometimes it works, sometime not. Definitely something to be avoided

Comment: @Steve reading your link about AddWithValue it may be difficult to avoid it without knowing the datatype prior to passing it to the method though?

Comment: That's (for me) one of the main reason to leave behind a do it all method. There is a lot of work to do it right and, unless you plan to reinvent something like EntityFramework, it doesn't worth the effort. Consider also to use a micro ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) and a set of Repository classes that know how to handle your object model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is injection-safe as long as you are in complete control of the `string tbl` and `string col`'s values, because these are the two strings from which you insert any parts into the SQL string sent to RDBMS.

I would turn this implementation around, and pass a collection of *separate* column values, rather than passing a comma-separated list of columns. The reason for this is that it's more straightforward to re-assemble a string than to disassemble one. For example, your way of parsing a string would break for tables with delimited identifiers containing commas.

This is a perfectly legal query<sup>*</sup>

```
SELECT [Return, Raw], [Return, Normalized] FROM Returns
```

Your method would fail because of embedded commas. If you pass an array of identifiers instead, you could easily reconstruct comma-separated list, like this:

```
string[] colNames = new[] {"[Return, Raw]", "[Return, Normalized]"};
var col = string.Join(", ", colNames);
```

<sup>*</sup> Although I would not necessarily recommend using names like that, you may need to work with existing databases that do not leave you a choice.

Comment: I agree. The method InsertWithParameters in itself is not injection-safe, only the combination of the two shown methods. If someone was able to modify the tbl parameter, they could pass in something like this: "accounts (username, role, password) values ('hacker', 'superadmin', '1234'); insert into tbl_jobLogs". And lo and behold the evildoer has injected a new user account.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Excellent point, I did not even consider that possiblity.  Thanks.